# How to extract 10 consecutive digits from a alphanumeric string?

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

This will give me whether or not a text_field value consists of 10 consecutive digits. Now, what if I need to extract those digits in a new field. How would that work?

```
select text_field, 
case when regexp_like(text_field,'|^[0-9]{10}$') then 'Y' else 'N' end check_col
from some_table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this.

```
SELECT text_field REGEXP_SUBSTR(text_field, '([[:digit:]]{10})$') FROM some_table;
```

Check this function `REGEXP_SUBSTR(source, regexp, position, occurrence, modes)` for details.

**REGEXP_SUBSTR(source, regexp, position, occurrence, modes)** returns a string with the part of source matched by the regular expression. If the match attempt fails, NULL is returned. You can use REGEXP_SUBSTR with a single string or with a column. You can use it in SELECT clauses to retrieve only a certain part of a column. The position parameter specifies the character position in the source string at which the match attempt should start. The first character has position 1. The occurrence parameter specifies which match to get. Set it to 1 to get the first match. If you specify a higher number, Oracle will continue to attempt to match the regex starting at the end of the previous match, until it found as many matches as you specified. The last match is then returned. If there are fewer matches, NULL is returned. Do not confuse this parameter with backreferences. Oracle does not provide a function to return the part of the string matched by a capturing group. The last three parameters are optional.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(column, 'regexp') FROM table;
match := REGEXP_SUBSTR('subject', 'regexp', 1, 1, 'i')
```

Comment: |^[0-9]{10}$ is not being accepted. [[:digit:]]{10} was readily accepted. :)

Comment: Honestly I was looking at the function, not the regex :) This `(|^[0-9]{10})$` works as well. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Strange. Both expressions works here. Check this [link](http://regex101.com/r/oV5nH2)

Comment: This is actually funny. It is not working here. Using Oracle SQL Developer. But how does that matter?

Comment: Maybe it's got to do something with the regex syntax on Oracle. Really silly :) I'll check it latter again; let me know if you were able to make it work in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

```
select text_field, regexp_substr(text_field, '[[:digit:]]{10}'),
case when regexp_like(text_field,'[[:digit:]]{10}') then 'Y' else 'N' end check_col
from some_table
```

This works.